# Using Custom Shaders in WorldWind Java / JOGL

Tags: java, shader, jogl, worldwind

*or* **Creating an IR effect in [WorldWind Java](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/)**

I need to emulate an infrared (IR) view in WorldWind, and I'm not sure about the best way to go about this.  I should point out that I *do not* need to *simulate* IR (i.e. no heat maps) -- I just need to produce a reasonable facsimile of a black-and-white IR display. I have very limited graphics knowledge and no prior experience with OpenGL, JOGL, or WorldWind.

Based on my research so far, it seems that the best approach is to use a custom shader.  However, as far as I can tell, WorldWind provides no high-level shader support.

I found the following relevant threads on a WorldWind forum, but I'm still not sure how to proceed:

- [GLSL Shader support that renders tiles correctly](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=20829)
- [Updating GLSL support with new JOGL](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=22333)
- [Normal mapping (GLSL shader)](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=21615)
- [GLSL fragment shader problem](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=25635)

To clarify my question(s):

**How do I integrate a GLSL shader into a WorldWind application, if that is in fact the best approach?  If not, how should I implement this effect?**

Comment: Very interested in the response - I'm using WorldWind in an application at work but never thought about using custom shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be fairly straightforward, thanks to the contributions of tve and what_nick in this thread: [GLSL Shader support that renders tiles correctly](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=20829).  Specifically, I reused the GLSL class contributed by tve (in [shader_support_051308.zip](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1923&d=1230072116)) and modified what_nick's sample code.

I defined a DecoratedLayer class that allows any layer to be "decorated" with a new rendering strategy, then defined a ShadingDecorator that sets up the GLSL shader before delegating to the underlying layer's `render` method:

```
public class DecoratedLayer implements Layer {
    private final Layer _layer;
    private final I_LayerDecorator _decorator;

    public DecoratedLayer(Layer layer, I_LayerDecorator decorator) {
        _layer = layer;
        _decorator = decorator;
    }

    @Override
    public void preRender(DrawContext dc) {
       _decorator.preRender(dc, _layer);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(DrawContext dc) {
       _decorator.render(dc, _layer);
    }

    // all other methods delegate to _layer
}

public class ShadingDecorator implements I_LayerDecorator {
    private GLSL glsl;
    private final File vertfile;
    private final File fragfile;

    public ShadingDecorator(final File vertexShaderFile, 
                            final File fragmentShaderFile) {
        vertfile = vertexShaderFile;
        fragfile = fragmentShaderFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void preRender(DrawContext dc, Layer layer) {
        if (glsl == null) {
            glsl = new GLSL(dc.getGL());
            glsl.loadVertexShader(vertfile);
            glsl.loadFragmentShader(fragfile);
        }
        layer.preRender(dc);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(DrawContext dc, Layer layer) {
        if (glsl != null) {
            glsl.useShaders();
            glsl.startShader();
            GL gl = dc.getGL();
            gl.glUniform1i(glsl.getUniformLocation("tile_image"), 0);

            layer.render(dc);

            glsl.endShader();
        }
    }
}
```

More work is needed to make this fully general, but this should be a reasonable starting point.